# React Native adding and remove packages as features or plugin at runtime

Tags: react-native

I am working on building a modular React Native App for Enterprises in which it requires adding or remove packages as features or plugins (without updating the app). The following shall be a process

1. An enterprise user shall download and install a **base mobile Android/iOS app** (build in React Native) in a mobile handset
2. From the back-end, multiple packages or features (may defer with other enterprises) shall be configured for an enterprise
3. The multiple pre-built packages/modules shall be kept at a store at the backend
4. The enterprise user shall automatically get the packages as features in the mobile app using step 1 above, post step 2

I don't have any issue handling and building the backend and react native app. I am struggling that how dynamically adding/removing a package is possible in the existing **base mobile app** based on backend configuration.

Comment: I don't know the process or the feasibility of what you have stated in the question. but can't you just bake most of the features/plugin right inside the react native app, then enable or disable it based on your business logic. say you have chat module which is right there inside the app but it is not visible to the end user until or unless you enable it from the backend? This should help in your situation and updating mobile apps are the preferred  way of deploying updates to the user.

Comment: @SahilManchanda what you have suggested can work but my worry is that it would increase app size. It would be fine if a module bundle is dynamically added to the app when the related feature is enabled. It would need to explore if react-native-bundle-splitter or repack as suggested by Bojke below, could help into this.

Comment: by looking at the complexity level and ease to manage in longer this trade off seems to be fine but ultimately it's your decision. Best of luck. if you get any success do post the steps as an answer so that others could benefit also :)

Comment: @SahilManchanda hope Expo is doing the same so it runs a new code into its base code. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Good question! I have no idea on how expo is able to run examples over the air. I will try to do some research on this topic over the weekend.

Comment: Ajay, I tried to find something useful but couldn't figure out anything.

Answer (score 0):

If those packages/features are javascript only you can try `codepush`. This will allow to change the js bundle runtime. Check out this section: [Dynamic Deployment Assignment](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push#dynamic-deployment-assignment)

However if those packages require native implementation the only solution would be to split your code. This way you would need to ship every package in the apk, but the main bundle will contain only the code of the "base" app and the other code with the additional features would be loaded runtime. This will also bring a huge performance boost.
You can easily control which user sees what by conditionally rendering the screens by a role or whatever.

For code splitting you can check out these repos:
[react-native-bundle-splitter](https://github.com/kirillzyusko/react-native-bundle-splitter) or [repack](https://github.com/callstack/repack)

Comment: Could you please share more detail with a very basic code.

Comment: Well, not really. You can check out each repo's example app/readme and decide which one fits you the most. Maybe the easiest one to implement would be `react-native-bundle-splitter`, but as far as I know this can only split the code based on screens ( never tried it myself ) . Repack is still beta, but very promising, unfortunately it's pretty complicated and needs advanced webpack knowledge. Good luck 